# Sending array from URL.Action and getting null in controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a function that after adding items in a for loop calls the controller through the action URL sending the `arr` parameter (array), I see that it sends the data but null appears in the controller parameter. I wanted to know what could be wrong?

Javscript Function

```
function Submit() {
  QRCodeval.forEach((code) => arr.push(code.innerHTML));
  window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ReceivedFromBarCode","PurchaseOrder")?" +arr;
}
```

Link generated by the controller:

`http://localhost:56978/PurchaseOrder/ReceivedFromBarCode?JJJKP,RRPRQ,PPLQR`

Controller where I get null in the arr parameter.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ReceivedFromBarCode(string[] arr)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC model binder expects arrays to be passed in the following format: `arr=value1&arr=value2&...`

You can use `map()` and `join()` to create the correct format. But you'll also need to encode the values since they are parameters in a URL. [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) can help with that:

```
let urlParams = array.map((val) => { 
                         return `arr=${encodeURIComponent(val)}` 
                     }).join('&');

window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ReceivedFromBarCode","PurchaseOrder")?" 
                         + urlParams;
```

And append the `urlParams` to your URL. Example output in snippet below:

```js
let array = ["value1", "http://example.com?x=1", "<script>alert('')</sctipt>"];

let urlParams = array.map((val) => { 
                       return `arr=${encodeURIComponent(val)}` 
                     }).join('&');

console.log(urlParams);
```